# Session keep showing up as text and does not show the value in asp

Tags: html, asp-classic

here is my html code:

```
<h2><% (Session("ID")) %></h2>
```

it supposed to have a value but it keeps it as a simple text like `<% (Session("ID")) %>`
and adding `Respose.Write` doesn't help me here

thanks for the help

Comment: Did you try `<h2><%= Session("ID") %></h2>`? Also it's `<h2><% Response.Write(Session("ID")) %></h2>` if you don't want to do the shorthand version. Is that a typo in your question or might explain why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add an equal sign (=) after the <%.  Should be:

```
<h2><%=Session("ID")%></h2>
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_syntax.asp